# Conditional model validations dependent on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller

I have a user model, that stores, amongst other things, the users address. When creating an account (user_sessions controller) I only wish to validate the presence of their name, the address is optional.

When they upgrade their account (upgrade controller) i want to validate that that their full address is entered.

Is there an elegant way of having a conditional validation based on the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried creating a new model that inherits from the old one.  So you could have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :address
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class UpgradedUser < User
  validates_precense_of :address
end
```

Since it inherits from the `User` class, the `UpgradedUser` class has validations for both address and name. And this solution would still be only using one database table. Because they are still one table, you'd have to add a `:account_status` column or something to determine whether an account has been upgraded or not.

In your upgraded_users controller you would have a standard update method:

```
class upgraded_users_controller   

  def update
    @upgraded_user = UpgradedUser.find params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @upgraded_user.update_attributes params[:user]
        format.html { redirect_to @upgraded_user }
      end
    end
```

This method will access the same User table just like the `users_controller`  would, but its simply doing so through the `UpgradedUser` model instead, and therefore would check the validators on save for both name and address presence.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this some more please, I have tried to implement it, but am struggling. Within my upgrade controller, how do I retrieve the existing user details before adding the additional address details through the upgradeduser?

Comment: @pingu updated my answer above ^^.  But basically you treat it exactly like you would an update from the normal `users_controller`, just this time you're accessing the table through the `UpgradedUser` model.

Answer (score 2):

### Decorator / Instance Extension

You could use a decorator pattern to accomplish this. Instance extension is another option. Because we're using ruby and it's more fun here's the instance extension way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :decorator_validations

  protected

  def decorator_validations
    # noop at this point
  end
end


module User::Upgrader

  def upgrade!
    # do whatever upgrade operation is needed
    save
  end

  protected

  def decorator_validations
    super
    self.errors.add(:address, 'needs to be provided') unless self.address.present?
  end
end
```

And in your controller:

```
def upgrade
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.extend User::Upgrader
  if @user.upgrade!
    # success case
  else
    # failure case
  end
end
```

### Command Pattern

An alternative way is to use a command pattern:

```
class UserUpgrader

 def initialize(user)
   @user = user
 end

 def call
   validate_upgrade_state
   return false if @user.errors.present?
   @user.update_attribute(:upgraded, true)
 end

 protected

 def validate_upgrade_state
   @user.errors.add(:address, 'must be present') unless @user.address.present?
 end
end
```

And in this case your controller would look like:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if UserUpgrader.new(@user).call
 # success case
else
 # failure case
end
```

The nice thing about both of these solutions is they are very very testable.